# AppleScript-how does "du -sh " command convert file size to human readable

Tags: applescript

I want to check the size of a Folder on MacOS.
The folder path is "/Volumes/TSAIYUB/Finished/test folder".
I run this command in terminal:

```
du -s /Volumes/TSAIYUB/Finished/test\ folder
```

The output is 9609728.
Then I run this command:

```
du -sh /Volumes/TSAIYUB/Finished/test\ folder
```

The output is 4.6GB.
In AppleScript, I run this code:

```
on getSize(posixPath)
    --the code is from:
    --https://forum.latenightsw.com/t/getting-file-folder-sizes-system-events-vs-info-for/904
    set cmdStr to "du -s " & quoted form of posixPath
    set itemSizeStr to (do shell script cmdStr)
    set itemSize to (first word of itemSizeStr)
    --set itemSizeGB to itemSize / (1024 ^ 3)
    return itemSize
end getSize

my getSize("/Volumes/TSAIYUB/Finished/test folder")
```

The output is 9609728. It's same with the output of "du -s "
Then I try to convert this value to human readable in AppleScript. I find this code on Internet:

```
on convertByteSize(byteSize, KBSize, decPlaces)
    --the code is from:
    --https://macscripter.net/viewtopic.php?id=37035
    if (KBSize is missing value) then set KBSize to 1000 + 24 * (((system attribute "sysv") < 4192) as integer)

    if (byteSize is 1) then
        set conversion to "1 byte" as Unicode text
    else if (byteSize < KBSize) then
        set conversion to (byteSize as Unicode text) & " bytes"
    else
        set conversion to "Oooh lots!" -- Default in case yottabytes isn't enough!
        set suffixes to {" K", " MB", " GB", " TB", " PB", " EB", " ZB", " YB"}
        set dpShift to ((10 ^ 0.5) ^ 2) * (10 ^ (decPlaces - 1)) -- (10 ^ decPlaces) convolutedly to try to shake out any floating-point errors.
        repeat with p from 1 to (count suffixes)
            if (byteSize < (KBSize ^ (p + 1))) then
                tell ((byteSize / (KBSize ^ p)) * dpShift) to set conversion to (((it div 0.5 - it div 1) / dpShift) as Unicode text) & item p of suffixes
                exit repeat
            end if
        end repeat
    end if

    return conversion
end convertByteSize

my convertByteSize(9609728, 1000, 0)
```

The output is 10MB. WEIRD! I googled "how does du command convert byte size to human readable", but nothing useful can find. And the code about this topic are mostly in Java, C, or other language. I don't understand them, since I only write some simple AppleScript for automation.Hope someone can tell me what's wrong with this AppleScript handler!

Comment: Are you asking about the `du` human readable option (`-h`), or using AppleScript to convert numbers to a more human readable form?

Comment: hi @red_menace , I want to use AppleScript to convert bytes size to human readable file size. But the output of the AppleScript is different from the output of "du -sh " in terminal. Maybe it has something wrong with the handler i use.

Comment: `du -s` does not give the size in bytes, but in *blocks*. By default it assumes 512-byte blocks, so you'd need to multiply its output by 512 to get bytes. There are also ways to modify its blocksize with options (`-k`, `-m`, or `-g`) or with the `BLOCKSIZE` environment variable. See the man page for details.

Comment: By using 0 decimal places, it is getting rounded up to the next whole.  Using something like `convertByteSize(9609728, 1000, 2)` should be closer to what you are looking for.

Comment: @Gordon Davisson 's answer is correct. The output of "du -s " need to be multiplied by 512. Thanks for all the replies.